# Job Scheduler is not working in Android 7

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

In my android app I have created Job Scheduler. It works fine in all versions of android except android 7. After lots of research I came to know that the time of Job Scheduler should not be less than 15 mins in android noughat. After changing the time duration the service inside the job scheduler run only once after 15 min, it is unable to invoke the activity if I clear the app from recent apps.

Why am I unable to invoke the activity and how can I solve this?

Comment: I know it's too late but still a have a suggestion.

Why don't you try to open an app through notification instead invoking app activity.

Like if your scheduler done job then in the end scheduler will notify user through notification and onclick of notification, app will open it.